# TypeScript: `'keyof R'` is not assignable to type 'string' because it can be either 'string | number | symbol'

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes a key of an object, is there a way to narrow the type of the key to only `string`

```
function foo<R, K extends keyof R>(obj: R, key: K, array: string[]) {
  array.push(key); // Error: Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    
  // omit implementation details...
  return obj[key];
}
```

So TS compiler says that `'keyof R'` is not assignable to type 'string' because it can be either  'string | number | symbol' . I wonder if there is a way to narrow its type to only `string` so we can exclude `number` and `symbol` from it.

I tried this but it seems wrong syntactically

```
function foo<R, K extends Extract(keyof R, string)>(obj: R, key: K, array: string[]) {
  array.push(key);

  // omit implementation details...
  return obj[key];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your generic syntax is wrong, `Extract(A, B)` needs to be `Extract<A, B>`, so function `foo<R, K extends Extract<keyof R, string>>(obj: R, key: K, array: string[])`.

That said there is really no reason to have your function generic on *two* things when you care about *one* object:

```js
function foo<R>(obj: R, key: Extract<keyof R, string>, array: string[]): void {
  array.push(key);
}
```

Would work just as well and is much simpler.

You need the second type if you want to return the object's value at the key, and you end up with:

```js
function foo<R, T extends Extract<keyof R, string>>(obj: R, key: T, array: string[]): R[T] {
  array.push(key);
  return obj[key];
}
foo({x: 3, y: 5}, 'x', array);
```